# how i can build more than one plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, plot, tkinter-canvas

I create program on python and tkinter that can build plot. But I can`t build more than one plot at one time. Please help me. Explain how i can implement it.

```
from tkinter import *
import math

wind = Tk()
wind.geometry("400x400")

canw = Canvas(wind, width=400, height=400)
canw.pack()
canw.place(x=-1, y=-1)


lines_index = 0
numbers = -8

#create cages(like in notebook) [one cage = 10x10 px]
while lines_index <= 40:
    if lines_index == 20:
        canw.create_line(0, 0+10*lines_index, 400, 0+10*lines_index, fill="#000", width=2)     #x_line
        canw.create_line(10*lines_index, 0, 10*lines_index, 400, fill="#000", width=2)      #y_line
    else:
        canw.create_line(0, 0+10*lines_index, 400, 0+10*lines_index, fill="#4C8098")     #x_line
        canw.create_line(10*lines_index, 0, 10*lines_index, 400, fill="#4C8098")      #y_line
    lines_index = lines_index + 1
    numbers = numbers + 1
    print(lines_index, numbers)

 

# b = [-16,-15,-14,-13,-12,-11,-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,
#     0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]     #test properties

# fun_index = 1     #don`t use now

b = []  #array for properties
i = -20
while i <= 20:
    b.append(i)
    i= i + 0.01     #change accuracy 
    print(i)


for x in b:     #loop create points for plot
    y = x**2
    # y = (6*(x**2))+(2*x)+8
    # y = (6*(x**2))+8
    # y= 3*(x+3)
    # y = 3**x
    # y=x**3
    # y = x**(1/2)   #not work
    # y = 1/x
    canw.create_oval((x*10)+200, -(y*10)+200, (x*10)+200, -(y*10)+200, outline='red', fill="red")
    print(y)


wind.mainloop()
```

I try to use if else in loop(where creates points for plot) but it not a good idea. Becase all points divided into all amount of plots.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can`t build more than one plot at one time"? Do you mean once the plot is done, you cannot draw extra plots?

Comment: I mean that i can`t use loop to draw more plots on canwas at one time. For example, i need to watch where this plots are intersect. I`m so sorry if i explain it bad. I bad at english. Thanks.

Comment: It is still not clear what your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, note that the `create_oval` method draws ellipses (or circles in special cases where you satisfy the proper radius condition) and it has inputs like `x0, y0, x1, y1` where:

"The ellipse is fit into a rectangle defined by the coordinates `(x0, y0)` of the top left corner and the coordinates `(x1, y1)` of a point just outside of the bottom right corner.".

Source: https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/create_oval.html

Secondly, your coordinate system is a bit off. In the plot popping up, your origin `(0,0)` point is actually at the very top left corner of the plot. You can verify this by doing something like `canw.create_oval(50, 50, 20, 20, outline='red', fill="red")` and see that the circle is actually near to the top left corner of the plot window instead of being near to the origin you seem to define with your two main black lines. Thus, in the `for x in b:` loop of the code you've shared, your endeavors to plot multiple ellipses on the same canvas are in-vain because these ellipses go well beyond the visible area.

The solution is to shift the origin of the coordinate system to fit exactly into the desired `(0,0)` point, i.e., where the two black lines intersect. You can achieve this by including offsets of value `200` (since your grids are 10x10):

```
canw.create_oval(x1+200, -y1+200, x2+200, -y2+200, outline='red', fill="red")
```

However, there is also an important point to which you need to pay attention here. The `(x0,y0)`, and `(x1,y1)` are **not** top left and bottom right (respectively) corners of the rectangle that the ellipse is fit into, but rather after the origin shift, `(x0,y0)` becomes the **bottom left**, and `(x1,y1)` becomes the **top right** corner of the rectangle.

Having these in mind, you can plot whatever you want inside the `for` loop. Since I did not understand what you are (mathematically) trying to plot, I cannot give you a test case here, but if you can provide me with any special case, I can help further by updating my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what this sentence means, why do you use if else in the loop?

> I try to use if else in loop(where creates points for plot) but it not a good idea.

If you only want to draw multiple plots at the same timet, just change the loop to this:

```
for x in b:
    y1 = x**2 # Plot 1
    canw.create_oval((x*10)+200, -(y1*10)+200, (x*10)+200, -(y1*10)+200, outline='red', fill="red")
    y2 = x**3 # Plot 2
    canw.create_oval((x*10)+200, -(y2*10)+200, (x*10)+200, -(y2*10)+200, outline='green', fill="green")
    try:
        y3 = math.sqrt(x) # Plot 3
        canw.create_oval((x*10)+200, -(y3*10)+200, (x*10)+200, -(y3*10)+200, outline='yellow', fill="yellow")
    except ValueError: # Out of domain
        pass
```

Comment: `canw.create_oval(x0, y0, x1, y1, option, ...)` already draws an ellipse (or circle) for a single set of `(x0,y0)` and `(x1,y1)` points, which means multiple plots are already drawn inside the `for` loop. The reason he cannot see these plots is his calculations of points and the fact that the origin shift has changed the perception of the rectangle points within which the ellipse is going to be drawn.

Comment: thanks, you really help me. i fell myself so idiot. how i can`t think about it. :)